# Why RANSAC gives me different results every time I run it on the same point cloud?

Tags: ransac

I am experimenting with the RANSAC algorithm, namely the RANSAC implementation from this paper: http://cg.cs.uni-bonn.de/en/publications/paper-details/schnabel-2007-efficient/

I use the code base what the authors provided. I am trying to segment objects, like a mug obtained with Kinect 1 into primitive shapes.

My problem is, that every time i run the primitive shape detection on the same object point cloud, I get different results, like for one run I get detected 3 cylinders and one cone and for the next run I get detected 2 torus and 1 sphere.

I know that the first points for the candidate object primitive is picked randomly. So in the code I set the random seed parameter to a static number. In that case my result is always the same as it should be. But shouldn't RANSAC produce the same or almost the same results even with a non static seed like the actual time for example?

Answer (score 2):

RANSAC stands for RANdom SAmple Consensus and is an iterative algorithm that, in its habitual form, stops after a maximum number of iteration or if a certain criterion (minimization of error) is attained. The "random" part means that depending of the dataset, it is possible that applying RANSAC doesn't always yield the same result, especially when it stops because of getting to the max number of iterations instead of minimizing the error enough. There are many numerical solvers that behave that way.
[In computing, a Monte Carlo algorithm is a randomized algorithm whose running time is deterministic, but whose output may be incorrect with a certain (typically small) probability.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_algorithm) It is the opposite of so-called "Las Vegas" algorithms. [In computing, a Las Vegas algorithm is a randomized algorithm that always gives correct results; that is, it always produces the correct result or it informs about the failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm), but it cannot guaranty to do so within a set of time/computation resources.

Now, I don't know for the specific implementation you mention, but this is how it works for that kind of algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as RANSAC have a random component to it, the precision of your algorithm (variability of the results) depends on the complexity of the scene/object you are trying to detect and segment.

There are many factors that play some part in the accuracy and precision when running an algorithm based on RANSAC. It is usually a function of the resolution of your data (point density in this case), the complexity of the object and the approach used in the detection and segmentation.

Usually, when working with a random component in the processing, a good idea is to run the same scene/object a number of times and by some sort of voting (frequentist approach), select the most probable result.